# Optimized solution for traversing list of objects (groups) and each object has list of objects, and I need to apply inheritance

Tags: java, arrays, spring, optimization, arraylist

I am seeking an optimized solution for traversing a list of objects (groups) where I need to apply inheritance:

For example :

Level4:

```
[Group 1 , group 2 , group 1] ---> each Group [BankArray]  ---> each BankArray [obj 1 ,obj2 ,obj 2]

Same for level 3 
Same for level 2
Same for level 1
```

And each group not has only BankArray, but has also bankDetail object.

All levels same structure.

What I need to do: take first object obj 1 and walk through all the other level lists and see if there is any object (same currency and same operationType (does not matter the other attribute)) and if I found similarity should delete this object from level 3 or 2 or 1 wherever I found it.

So this step from 4 with 3.
4 with 2.
3 with 1.

then will start next step from level 3 after it was updated (deleted the duplication):

3 with 2
3 with 1

then will start next step from level 2 after it was updated (deleted the duplication):

2 with 1

I was thinking on some solutions to  do that 3 solutions but not complete,
First solution: with loops then remove the the duplication from the list it self () I don't know if it possible: And this only between 4 and 3 only

```
        for (BankGroup bankGroup4 : bankGroupArrayL4) {
         for(BankDetail four :bankDetailLinkageGroup4.getBankDetailArray() ) {
            for (BankDetailLGroup bankDetailGroup3 : bankDetailGroupArrayL3) {
                for(BankDetail three :bankDetailGroup3.getBankDetailArray() ) {
                    if(four.getPymtCrryCd().equals(three.getPymtCrryCd()) && four.getOprnTyp().equals(three.getOprnTyp())) {
                        bankDetailLGroup3.getBankDetailArray().remove(three);
                    }
                }
```

Solution 2:
Not completed and give me conversion error but we talk about the logic it self :

```
        Boolean l4 = (!bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL4.isEmpty() && bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL4 != null);
    Boolean l3 = (!bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL3.isEmpty() && bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL3 != null);
    Boolean l2 = (!bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL2.isEmpty() && bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL2 != null);
    Boolean l1 = (!bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL1.isEmpty() && bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL1 != null);
    if (l4) {
        List<BankDetailLinkage> objectsL4 = bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL4.stream()
                .flatMap(a -> a.getBankDetailLinkageArray().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (l3) {
            List<BankDetailLinkage> objectsL3 = bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayL3.stream()
                    .flatMap(a -> a.getBankDetailLinkageArray().stream())
                    .filter(two -> objectsL4.stream()
                    .anyMatch(one -> one.getPymtCrryCd().equals(two.getPymtCrryCd())&&
                    two.getOprnTyp().equals(one.getOprnTyp())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    }
```

Solution 3: by creating only one method but not completed as well:

```
    private void deleteOrAdd(List<BankDetailLinkageGroup> bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayA,
        List<BankDetailLinkageGroup> bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayB, Set<BankDetailLinkage> blackList) {
    if (bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayB.isEmpty() && bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayB == null) {
        for (BankDetailLinkageGroup bankDetailLinkageGroup : bankDetailLinkageGroupArrayA) {
            for (BankDetailLinkage bankDetailLinkage : bankDetailLinkageGroup.getBankDetailLinkageArray()) {
                if (blackList.isEmpty() && blackList == null) {
                    blackList.add(bankDetailLinkage);
                } else {
                    // compare with blackList
                    for (BankDetailLinkage bankDetailLinkageBlackList : blackList) {
                        if (bankDetailLinkage.getPymtCrryCd().equals(bankDetailLinkageBlackList.getPymtCrryCd())
                                && bankDetailLinkage.getOprnTyp().equals(bankDetailLinkageBlackList.getOprnTyp())) {
                            bankDetailLinkageGroup.getBankDetailLinkageArray().remove(bankDetailLinkage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // compare a with b and with blackList
    }
}
```

How can I find a solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean with `inheritance`? I cannot find an example of inheritance in your code. Are you talking about recursive / tree-like structures? This problem here cries for a recursive solution: Create a starter method, that maybe creates Set or Maps for checking 'equality' (where certain objects that need to be checked are put in,, maybe also results), then starts the recursive function. The recursive function receives one object, analyses that, maybe acts upon it, then iterates through its lists, each time calling itself (method) for each object in those lists.

Comment: Thanks , i meant by inheritance , that what in level 4   as objects , if i found similar at level 3 should be deleted  and return back level 3 after the changes and same with level 2 ...etc

Comment: This part example of what i said

       if (bankDetailLinkage.getPymtCrryCd().equals(bankDetailLinkageBlackList.getPymtCrryCd())
                                && bankDetailLinkage.getOprnTyp().equals(bankDetailLinkageBlackList.getOprnTyp())) {
                            bankDetailLinkageGroup.getBankDetailLinkageArray().remove(bankDetailLinkage);

Comment: So i remove from list  which inside level 3 when i found similarity